# a unitary does not in general lift to a unitary

Tags: c-star-algebras, k-theory, topological-k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Consider the restriction map $\pi:C(\mathbb{D})\rightarrow C(\mathbb{T})$, where $\Bbb D$ is the closed unit disk and $\Bbb T$ is the unit circle. Suppose $v\in C(\Bbb T)$ is a unitary such that $v(z)=z$; why doesn't there exist a unitary $u\in C(\Bbb D)$ such that $\pi(u)=v$?

Comment: For anyone looking into this, $u$ as in the question [cannot even be invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4661007/22857).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a fact from topology: the identity map $v:\mathbb{T}\to\mathbb{T}$ cannot be extended continuously to a map $u:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{T}$.  You can prove this using the fundamental group, for instance: $\pi_1(\mathbb{T})$ is nontrivial so $v$ induces a nontrivial map on fundamental groups and in particular is not nullhomotopic, but if it extended to $\mathbb{D}$ it would be nullhomotopic since $\mathbb{D}$ is contractible.

Comment: But $u$ is a map from $\Bbb D$ to $\Bbb C$.

Comment: If it's unitary it must map to $\mathbb{T}$.

Comment: oh,I see.Thanks!